# GCC 4.6.2 error: conflicting types for ‘psignal’

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

I'm trying to install gcc-4.6.2 on a node of a cluster. Unfortunatelly this node doesn't have an internet connection so I'm tryng to do everything manually.
I've installed all the required packages and I've run the config file with the following parameters:

```
./configure --with-newlib --prefix=/usr/lib64/gcc-4.6.2 --disable-libssp 
--enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-__cxa_atexit 
--enable-clocale=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,java 
--with-cpu=generic --build=x86_64-redhat-linux               
--host=x86_64-redhat-linux --target=x86_64-redhat-linux 
--with-target-subdir=x86_64-redhat-linux --with-mpfr=/usr/local/lib 
--with-gmp=/usr/local/lib --with-mpc=/usr/local/lib
```

However when I make it I got the following error:

```
../.././libiberty/strsignal.c:555: error: conflicting types for ‘psignal’
/usr/include/signal.h:141: error: previous declaration of ‘psignal’ was here
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I see three potential problems with your configure invocation:

- You've specified `--build`, `--host`, and `--target`, but they're all the same.  This puts the build in "make me a cross-compiler" mode despite your not actually getting a cross-compiler out of it.  This is an abnormal thing to do and probably doesn't work correctly.  Try deleting all three of those options.  If the node you're building on is *not* `x86_64-redhat-linux` and you really did want a cross compiler to that target, specify `--target` *only*.
- You've specified `--with-newlib`, but your `--target` selection is `x86_64-redhat-linux`.  Last I heard, newlib does not support this OS -- it's a minimal C library for embedded work.  Try taking that out too.
- There is no `--with-target-subdir` option.  That's harmless in itself -- configure ignores unrecognized `--with` and `--enable` options -- but I wonder what it was *meant* to do.  Did you copy this configure invocation from somewhere?

See http://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html for further advice.

(Do you actually have a use for the Java compiler? If not, disable it and your build will be about four times as fast.)

Comment: I run again with this `./configure --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,java --with-cpu=generic --with-mpfr=/usr/local/lib --with-gmp=/usr/local/lib --with-mpc=/usr/local/lib` but I got the following error `configure: error: in `/usr/lib64/gcc-4.6.2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc': configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile.
`

Comment: That suggests something wrong with your bootstrap compiler.  Is there already a compiler installed?  Does it work for trivial test programs?  I may be able to be more specific if you post the contents of `config.log` somewhere (not here, please, it'll be huge; put it on a pastebin or something like that and post a link)

Comment: I have a 2 previous version of gcc 3.4.6 and gcc 4.1.2.

Comment: Here you can download the config.log [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qshce3snvz8913a/config.log?n=19284518)

Comment: That config.log does not match either of the configure invocations you showed.  In particular, it has `--enable-languages=c,c++,f77` instead of `c,c++,java`, and it got well past the "cannot compute suffix of object files" point, bombing out because "`The following requested languages could not be built: f77 Supported languages are: c,c++,fortran,go,java,lto,objc,obj-c++`"  (F77 was what the Fortran compiler *used* to be called, but it was renamed about ten years ago, when it grew Fortran 90 support.  If you want Fortran, say `--enable-languages=c,c++,fortran`.)

Comment: Some libraries are also missing, but I think they are optional.